# Efficient management of received data from websockets with node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, websocket

I am working on a node js application, in which I have around 100 websocket subscriptions active, received many information simultaneously.

I have to store and update individual information based on each subscription. However, I am not sure regarding the best way to efficiently store the information. I am currently thinking about using a large array and store the information in there (cache based) or use mongoDB (or postgreSQL..). However, I am worried about the many DB accesses due to the many subscription and the related updates.

I would really appreciate if you could give me some advice on how to store and manage the information.

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: What type of information is it? How much? How often will each socket receive info that needs to be stored?

Comment: Each subscription receives one new piece of information all 2 to 8 seconds. The information itself is a rather small piece of data, like the following: 
["id": "141923924892143129", "lastVisitTimestamp": 21482190483328", "name": "Thomas", "age": "23", "meetsWithId": "2219232021044"]

Based on the received timestamp I have to update the array, thus I cannot just store each new information in a database, but have to update the array accordingly (using lodash and splice).

Comment: You could keep the active connections data into https://redis.io, it's very quick to read/write because it's in memory, moreover you could share this "session" storage between servers. But you could store the session data when the user disconnect of the socket into a persistent space, like postgreSQL or mongo